# Which version of null should I use?

Tags: vba, excel

Excel keeps coming up with an error message saying: 
Compile Error

Invalid Use of Object

```
If range("C13:17").Find(11) = Nothing Then
                'Do nothing
            Else
                range(findeleven).Select
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 1
            End If
```

Please help :-)

BTW it's written in VBA

Comment: try `Is Nothing` -- not `= Nothing`

Comment: You can shorten your code a bit by using the negation: `If Not Range("C13:17").Find(11) Is Nothing Then` and then your code.

Comment: "C13:17" should be "C13:C17"

Comment: @HuguesPaquetBlanchette Find can take a single argument _(the "What" argument to be precise)_ The others are optional and if omitted will default to the last user supplied settings.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you :)

```css
Sub Search()
Range("C13:C17").Select
With Selection
Set c = .Find(11, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
                
            Else
                Range("Your range").Select
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 1
            End If
End With
End Sub
```